# Getting class cast exception using iterator or for loop

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I have a list and I need to iterate it, its giving me class cast exception even after using Iterator or for loop, giving me the problem as

the code is as follows,

```
List<DataLoaderIndex> dataList = new ArrayList<DataLoaderIndex>();

dataList = dataLoaderIndexDAO.getDataSourceStatus(uploadFrequency,reportEndDate);

Map<String,String> mapData = new HashMap<String,String>();

Iterator<DataLoaderIndex> itrObj = dataList.iterator();
            while (itrObj.hasNext()) {
                DataLoaderIndex dlObj = itrObj.next();
                String dsName = dlObj.getDataSourceType();
                    String dsStatus = dlObj.getStatus();
                    mapData.put(dsName, dsStatus);

            }

/*for(int i=0;i<dataList.size();i++){
             String dsName = dataList.get(i).getDataSourceType();
             String dsStatus = dataList.get(i).getStatus();
             mapData.put(dsName, dsStatus);
         }*/
```

The DAO part goes here:

```
public List<DataLoaderIndex> getDataSourceStatus(String uploadFrequency,String reportEndDate){


    List<DataLoaderIndex> dataList = null;
    if(session!=null){
        Query query = session.createQuery("select dataSourceType,uploadedBy,status from DataLoaderIndex where DATE (reportEndDate) =:endate and UPPER(reportFreq) = UPPER(:uploadFreq)");  
        query.setString("endate", reportDate);
        query.setString("uploadFreq", uploadFrequency);
        dataList = query.list();
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

I get exception for the line

```
String dsName = dlObj.getDataSourceType();
```

...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.work.in.synct.entity.DataLoaderIndex
    at com.work.synct.service.dataloaderimpl.DataUploadDetailsService.getUploadStatus(DataUploadDetailsService.java:36)
```

Comment: getDataSourceType is not a string. So only you got the ClassCastException

Comment: Can you post the DataLoaderIndex class

Comment: Are you sure the exception is not thrown here: `DataLoaderIndex dlObj = itrObj.next();` ?  What is the return type of `dataLoaderIndexDAO.getDataSourceStatus()`?

Comment: I am agree with @kevin but there is significant reason for raising Exception on that line as Iterator is typed, not generic one.

Comment: @newuser : datasource type is a string, DataLoaderIndex is an entity which contains id,datasourcename,datasourceType,status

Comment: @KevinBowersox : u are right, the exception is thrown at DataLoaderIndex dlObj = itrObj.next();

Answer (score 0):

In the `DAO` method the query should be strongly typed by using `TypedQuery`.  Since the query is not typed at the moment it is returning a `List<Object[]>` which can be assigned to the `dataList` due to type erasure.  At runtime `List<DataLoaderIndex>` looses its type information so its can be assigned the `List<Object[]>`.

```
List<DataLoaderIndex> dataList = null;
if(session!=null){
    TypedQuery<DataLoaderIndex> query = session.createQuery("select dataSourceType," +
        "uploadedBy,status from DataLoaderIndex where DATE " +
           " (reportEndDate) =:endate and UPPER(reportFreq) = UPPER(:uploadFreq)", 
              DataLoaderIndex.class);


    query.setString("endate", reportDate);
    query.setString("uploadFreq", uploadFrequency);
    dataList = query.list();
}

return dataList;
```

**Update**

I just realized your not using JPA.  Instead try casting the returned list in the DAO method.  At some point you will need to upcast to the type `List<DataLoaderList>`

`dataList = (List<DataLoaderList>)query.list();`

Comment: No.. it gave me other errors when I used the abv code, at query.setString("endDate".... "The setString(String,String) is undefined for the type TypedQuery..."

Comment: Is the problem exists in the query?? I mean instead of "from dataLoader where..." I'm using "select blah,blah from dataLoader"??

Comment: @madhu Just realized your using straight hibernate and not jpa.  Try just casting dataList, `dataList = (List<DataLoaderIndex>)query.list();`